# Efficiency of Plain Functions vs. Immediate Functions?

Tags: javascript

Someone mentioned that immediate or self-executing functions have to store the whole stack.  Is this true...If so what are the pros and cons of using something like the module pattern (which is based on an immediate function) vs. a plain function?

A function is inherently private, but you can return items that you want to be public, so it can handle privacy.

The main difference I see, is that you don't have global imports or the ability to make sure that the developer ( wait that's me ) uses new with the function ( or it is complicated ).

In general when trying to provide privacy and state when should one use the module pattern and when should one just use a plain function?

A second side question is does a function provide state when used with new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any function closure that persists because there are lasting references to variables or functions inside it occupies some amount of memory.  In today's computers (even phones), this amount of memory is generally insignificant unless you're somehow repeating it thousands of times.  So, using the language features to solve your design problems is generally more important than worrying about this amount of memory.

When you say "the whole stack", the calling stack for a top-level self-executing function is very small.  There's really nothing else on the stack except for the one function that's being called.

A function is also an object.  So, when it's used with `new`, it creates a new object that can have state (it's properties) if you assign values to those properties.  That's one of the main ways that objects are created in javascript.  You can either call a function and examine it's return value  or you can use it with `new` and the function serves as the constructor for a new object.  A given function is usually designed to be used in one way or the other, not both.

The module pattern is generally used to control which variables are public and when making them public to put them into a structured namespace that uses very few top-level global variables.  It isn't really something you choose instead of self-executing functions because they don't really solve the same problem.  You can read more about the module pattern here: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/

You can read about a number of the options here: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth and http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-programming-patterns/.

It is easier to discuss the pros/cons of a given technique in light of a specific problem that one is trying to solve or a specific design issue rather than a generic discussion of which is better when the things you've asked about are not really solving equivalent issues.

The best reference I know of for protected and private members (which can be hacked into javascript, but are not a core language feature) is this one: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html.  You are making tradeoffs when you use this method instead of the default prototype feature of the language, but you can achieve privacy if you really need it.  But, you should know that javascript was not build with private or protected methods in mind so to get that level of privacy, you're using some conventions about how you write your code to get that.

Comment: +1 for saying _"it doesn't matter"_ in so many words... `;-)`

Comment: @gdoron - The OP does have about five somewhat confusing, question-like things they asked about so I tried to address each one - though none are particularly clear questions so it was hard to be brief.

Comment: @jfriend..I want to write object oriented code with private and public member as my de-facto way of writing code.  This is for 2 reasons. 1.) It is what is taught as best practice in intro courses at prestigious CS degree programs as the best way to write code.  This is how modern code is being written.  2.) Although it is typically taught with compiled languages like C++ and Java where you simply define a class and explicitly declare private and public members I still want to apply this concept to JavaScript...3.) This is a personal preference on how I want to style my code, I believe....

Comment: the language will support simple privacy...I've chosen not to use inheritance...because personally for me...I feel it is over-complicated...and that at some point in the near future JavaScript will support a more pure class model with classes and public and private members.  Updating my code to this new javacript will be easier if it is already in that "form"...

Comment: So my question is what it the best way to implement privacy in objects...is simple and I'm looking for one way to do it...I don't want to have to think out how to create private and public members each time I write a class....it's a waste of time for something that should be explicity stated as "class", "private", and "public", I've seen no less than 10 implementations of 1 thing.

Comment: You didnt' answer my question.  Give me a defacto way and tell me why I just shouldn't use a function...also I'm tired of it doesn't matter answers...I want to understand my code not say...well with all this processing power ...who cares...if I'm capturing the stack when I don't need to.

Comment: @gdoron..it does matter...+1 for taking the time to give me some useful info though.

Comment: @CS_2013 - The last paragraph I added to my answer contains the best reference and method I know of for getting true privacy in javascript objects. Privacy of methods is NOT an actual language feature so this is a bit of a hack using closures, but it works.

Comment: @CS_2013 - My advice when developing with javascript is to learn how the language was intended to be used first (that would be the prototype model for objects) rather than first trying to write C++ like code in javascript.  Then, after you understand the core tenets of the language, you can learn more advanced techniques if you feel the need to implement privacy in a few specific cases.

Comment: ...but a function has privacy function(){var private; function private(); var public={};return public;}...why do you ignore this?

Comment: @CS_2013 - I don't understand your latest comment.  Local variables or local functions are indeed private to a function.  I'm not ignoring that.  I use it all the time.  If you want private method on an object, you have to find a work-around for it (which I've given you a reference to) because it's not a core language feature.

Comment: So if I have private and public members what advantage do I gain by using the module pattern, or the revealing moduel pattern, or closures, or any other advanced JS thing? With private and public variables and functions I can emulate classes.

Comment: @CS_2013 - I don't think there is a precise defintion of the terms you're asking about so I'd need to see specific code examples to know what you're really asking.

Comment: I'll post fiddle tomorrow of two types of JS objects ( or class emulations )..if you have time please take a look.  Thanks.

Comment: @CS_2013 - FYI, my answer already explains advantages of the module pattern for containing and organizing globally accessible symbols (either functions or variables).  I use it for that in any significant project.

Comment: well...I'll read it again...and see if it touches upon the point I'm making.